# Axios unexpected end of stream in post when query params is too long

Tags: reactjs, axios

i have an issue, i've spent a day of searching results in google.

these are my two url
domain.api/v1/me/edit?access_token=ej............. (access_token length is 331)
domain.api/v1/me/security?access_token=ej............. (access_token length is 331)

The first result success, but for the second i'll always have an error message if the access_token length is 331

unexpected end of stream on Connection{domain.api, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/domain.api cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

if the access_token length is less than 331, the request succeed.
Can anyone help me?

```
let accessToken = 'access-token-331-caracthers-here';
let bodyParams = new FormData();
bodyParams.append('password_current', currentPwd);
bodyParams.append('password_new', confirmPwd);

axios.post(url, bodyParams, { params : {access_token : accessToken} } );
```